# CheckBox Not Sending Checked Value to Database C# Asp

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, checkbox

I am making a Attendance System in which I get Student Record from student table in a Gridview with a check box. tick the check box for students present and leave unchecked for absent.
After that i submit my record to attendance system.
Problem: If I Check or left unchecked it will show the Absent in Database Results after submission of attendance please check my code.

HTML

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="RecordTablesss.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="LabelSr" runat="server" Text=<%#Eval("Sr_Number") %>></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="LabelName" runat="server" Text=<%#Eval("Name") %>></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="LabelFN" runat="server" Text=<%#Eval("F_Name") %>></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckAttendence" runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:Button ID="ButtonSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="SaveAttendence" style="width: 61px" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code Behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Configuration;

namespace RecordTablesss
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            loadData();
        }

        protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void loadData()
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=HammadMaqbool;Initial Catalog=FYP_Demo;Integrated Security=True");
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Sr_Number,Name,F_Name From Registerd_Student",con);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

        protected void SaveAttendence(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
            {
                if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    string sta = "A";
                    CheckBox chkVar_ = row.FindControl("CheckAttendence") as CheckBox;
                    if (chkVar_.Checked)
                        sta = "P";

                    string StudentName = (row.FindControl("LabelName") as Label).Text;
                    string F_Name = (row.FindControl("LabelFN") as Label).Text;
                    int Number = int.Parse( (row.FindControl("LabelSr") as Label).Text);
                    //From Here to onword Database Operations. ..  
                    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=HammadMaqbool;Initial Catalog=FYP_Demo;Integrated Security=True");
                    conn.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Attendance_B values('"+Convert.ToInt32(Number)+"','"+StudentName+"','"+F_Name+"','"+sta+"')",conn);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }

        protected void ButtonSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: before asking the question debug your code first

Comment: @Hammad You forget to write  `else`...

Comment: @too_cool added else still problem is there. . .

Comment: Marc_s ok i will. . . Use parametrized quesries. .

Comment: string sta = "";
CheckBox chkVar_ = row.FindControl("CheckAttendence") as CheckBox;
if (chkVar_.Checked)
{
    sta = "P";
}
else
{
    sta = "A";
}
I Did it Recmnded by Thomas but the problem is still there?

Comment: @HammadMaqbool  Check my answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As You said @Thomas Krojer Answer also not solving your issue but it should do.

The resone you are getting `chkVar_.Checked` always false.because On `Page_Load` you are binding gridview again with out checking if it is a `postback`. 
Try this.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
          if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                loadData();
            }
    }
```

It will solve your problem surely..

Comment: thanks @too_cool, didn´t see before my lunch break, back now and +1 for you

Comment: @ThomasKrojer Welcome happy coding..you can accept my ans also :P

Comment: @ThomasKrojer Sorry man i didnot realize that it was ur comment.. little absentminded.. while replaying.. :D

Answer (score 3):

I think you do not really write what you mean:

```
string sta = "";
CheckBox chkVar_ = row.FindControl("CheckAttendence") as CheckBox;
if (chkVar_.Checked)
    sta = "P";
sta = "A";
```

I thin you mean:

```
string sta = "";
CheckBox chkVar_ = row.FindControl("CheckAttendence") as CheckBox;
if (chkVar_.Checked)
{
    sta = "P";
}
else
{
    sta = "A";
}
```

you see the difference?

Comment: it is still not working. . . :(
any other suggestion or solution please?

Comment: There are some Points - first: If user clicks the checkbox, did you step through your code to see, if the record is really inserted? second: if the record is inserted, how should your dataset get knowledge of this? you didn´t use the attendance table in your query.

Comment: points like? Can u solve this problem? If you can please ? Do it

Comment: Well Thomas I dnt think these points are going to solve my problem look...
CheckBox record got inserted but only with absend values... not dealing with the Present one this is the problem.. .  may be u r rite but i am not getting ur points exactly. .  if u can please solve it for me ?

Answer (score 1):

you just need to correct code

```
if (chkVar_.Checked)
{
    sta = "P";
}
else
{
    sta = "A";
}
```

Comment: correct code at page_load

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
if (Page.IsPostBack == false)
        {
            loadData();
}
        }